# Delete all items with a certain id from database

Tags: android, database

In my database I have 2 tables, one with lists and one with products. Each product has an id that means the number of the list it belongs. I want to create a menu for deleting all the products from a list. I have write this method, but it doesn't work. Any idea?

```
public boolean deleteproductall(long rowId) {
        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_2, KEY_LISTID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
```

table 2 :

```
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_2 = "Products";

public static final String KEY_ROWID2 = "_id";
public static final String KEY_LISTID = "ListId";
public static final String KEY_ITEM = "Item";
public static final String KEY_QUANTITY = "Quantity";
public static final String KEY_UNITS = "Units"
```

and for viewing only the product from a list, I used :

```
public Cursor fetchListId(String listId) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_2, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID2, KEY_LISTID, KEY_ITEM, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_UNITS },
                KEY_LISTID + "=" + listId, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
```

Comment: Check the log cat for database errors

Comment: what is the data type of ListId in database ?

Comment: is String. I solve my problem. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KEY_LISTID is defined as String, where as rowId is a long. Change it to this

```
return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_2, KEY_LISTID + "=" + Long.valueOf(rowId), null) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks..I think that my function works too,but I forgot to call filldata() after that...

Answer (score 2):

Please try this. It solves your problem.

```
public void deleteProductAll(long rowId)
{
    try
    {
        mDb.execSQL("DELETE FROM Products WHERE ListId = " + rowId);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```